# Comparing two same-shape band arrays, one against a set of conditions to then change the other one

Tags: python, numpy, array

first band and second band can be assumed to be the same shape.

I want to test the second band against two conditions (that it's not "invalid_data" and the value is one of the numbers in "list_of_desired_values").

For the index where those conditions were deemed true for the second band, I want to then change the first band at that same index to -9999 in this case.

I can't get this to work, and ideally I'd like to be able to do this within Numpy rather than a for loop for efficiency. Does anyone know an effective way to do this?

```
invalid_data = 5 #example
list_of_desired_values = [11, 2]
ds_first_band = original_raster_ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()
ds_second_band = original_raster_ds.GetRasterBand(2).ReadAsArray()
for index, x in enumerate(ds_second_band.flatten()):
    if x != invalid_data:
        if x in list_of_desired_values:
            ds_first_band.flatten()[index] = -9999
```